# Read CSV File to OrderedMap

Tags: scala

I'm reading the `CSV` File and adding data to `Map` in Scala.

```
 val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)), "UTF-8"))
 val inputFormat = CSVFormat.newFormat(delimiter.charAt(0)).withHeader().withQuote('"')                                
 import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
 import org.apache.commons.csv.{CSVFormat, CSVParser}

  val csvRecords = new CSVParser(br, inputFormat).getRecords.asScala
  val buffer = for (csvRecord <- csvRecords; if csvRecords != null && csvRecords.nonEmpty)
    yield csvRecord.toMap.asScala                              
    buffer.toList
```

But as the `Map` is not ordered I'm not able to read the columns in order. Is there any way to read the csvRecords in order?
The `CSV` file contains comma separated values along with the header. It should generate the output in `List[mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String]]` format something like `[["fname", "A", "lname", "B"], ["fname", "C", "lname", "D"]]`.

The above code is working but it is not preserving the order. For Ex: if CSV file contains columns in order fname, lname, the output map is having lname first and fname last.

Comment: update question with sample data and expected output please

Comment: I edited the question for sample output. I hope it will be clear.

Comment: does you input file contalns data with only fname , lname?

Comment: No. It has 100 columns. Just to simplify, I mentioned only 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, here's one way to create a list of `LinkedHashMap`s with elements in order:

```
// Assuming your CSV File has the following content:
fname,lname,grade
John,Doe,A
Ann,Cole,B
David,Jones,C
Mike,Duke,D
Jenn,Rivers,E

import collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

// Get indexed header from CSV
val indexedHeader = io.Source.fromFile("/path/to/csvfile").
  getLines.take(1).next.
  split(",").
  zipWithIndex

indexedHeader: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((fname,0), (lname,1), (grade,2))

// Aggregate LinkedHashMap using foldLeft
val ListOfLHM = for ( csvRecord <- csvRecords ) yield    
  indexedHeader.foldLeft(LinkedHashMap[String, String]())(
    (acc, x) => acc += (x._1 -> csvRecord.get(x._2))
  )

ListOfLHM: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String]] = ArrayBuffer(
  Map(fname -> John, lname -> Doe, grade -> A),
  Map(fname -> Ann, lname -> Cole, grade -> B),
  Map(fname -> David, lname -> Jones, grade -> C),
  Map(fname -> Mike, lname -> Duke, grade -> D),
  Map(fname -> Jenn, lname -> Rivers, grade -> E)
)
```